# jQuery - select attribute value of image with parent of specific class only

Tags: jquery, css

I have a list like so:

```
<ul>
    <li><div class="thumb"><img src="image-1.jpg"></div></li>
    <li><div class="thumb"><img src="image-2.jpg"></div></li>
    <li><div class="thumb selected"><img src="image-3.jpg"></div></li>
</ul>
```

How do I select the src attribute of the img that has the div parent with class= "selected"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the current `src` value:

```
var selectedSrc = $("div.selected img").attr("src")
```

To change the `src`:

```
$("div.selected img").attr("src", "someImage.jpg");
```

(Note that the selector `"div.selected img"` returns *all* images within that div, which is OK for you since there is only one. In the case that there were multiple, `.attr("src")` would return the `src` of the first one only, but `.attr("src", "SomeImage.jpg")` would change them all.)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the concise answer, there's the option to select the `img` and then filter:

```
$('img').filter(function() {
    return $(this).closest('div.selected').length;
}).attr('src');
```

But this is not terribly efficient, as a [jsPerf demonstrates](http://jsperf.com/a-brief-comparison-of-selection-methods).

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".thumbselected").children("img").attr("src");
```

Select the Class `.thumbselected`, select its children `img`, get the `src`.

Comment: There's no element with the class `thumbselected`.

Comment: @DavidThomas Oh, I didn't notice that, sorry, my bad.

Comment: Oh, no problem; I wasn't planning to down-vote, or anything; just pointing it out is all. =)